# Examples of ridiculously simple but useful web apps written in JavaScript?

Tags: web, html5-apps

I'm curious if anyone is using any web app that is extremely simple (very few lines of code). Something that helps you with something practical in your daily life? I'm learning JavaScript and I would like to see examples so that I can build my own, but I want it to be useful so I feel motivated enough to build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d3 page has some awesome examples of really neat yet simple applications: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/